# not able to read the last line of my log file using logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

my log file content is as below

```
55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043
55.3.244.2 GET /index.html 15820 0.049
55.3.244.3 GET /index.html 16780 0.053
55.3.244.4 GET /index.html 16784 0.056
55.3.244.5 GET /index.html 17689 0.059
```

and my conf file goes like this

```
input{
    file{
        path => "C:/ELK/Test/http.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter{
    grok{
        match => {"message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}"}
    }
}
output{
    stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}
```

when I executed the below command, it displayed the log data by skipping the last line 55.3.244.5 GET /index.html 17689 0.059.

```
C:\ELK\logstash-5.1.2\bin>logstash.bat -f test2.conf
```

In few forums, They are suggesting to enter a new line after the last log entry. I tried that as well. With that option it was reading the last line and skipping the first four entries!!!!. Anyways I don't want to alter my input source file.

How to overcome this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the *version* of logstash you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing out [ignore_older](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-ignore_older) within your **input**:

```
input{
    file{
        path => "C:/ELK/Test/http.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}
```

A glance at this [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-not-showing-any-output-solved/28636/27), could be helpful!